# Django Grappelli closer tabular lines

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views, django-grappelli

Is there a way to make labels and textfields closer to each other ?I am using django-grappelli. And can I define the change view such that all lines are in one column?

eg:

```
Label1   |_textfield1_|      Label2   |_textfield_|
Label3   |_Radiobuttons_|    Label4   |_large textfield_|
```

Comment: i would imagine this just boils down to altering the CSS code.  I've never used this project so maybe somebody has a setting suggestion.

Comment: Yeah definitely a CSS change. Override the grapelli CSS class to your liking.